# Como ler chave e valor de um json string?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Olhei alguns scripts e não achei nada parecido...
Teria como eu conseguir pegar apenas a parte:

> > EAAAAAYsX7TsBAsdfosfbsJZBrbPOzrIXkkdoCgqg5oT15RC3ZC4QZCAVg8WLXugwhuYsuUi0E92XBEuTRge0HZC298cwYjNVPbnBZAIpOL9kshfisdisM3MuCg8kALZB0sKjunVWTSMmTYq1dUfK8eQ81i8aNcLmzsfhtdFON6XvmRA5oI8MCVZAOKPD3ROVQbwfwQZA54zGe6zrah6nw5Lz07VrAZD

Com o comando explode, ou com outro?

Abaixo é o código completo do jeito que estou gerando:
Deixei em negrito para quem for me dar uma ajudinha, dar uma conferida de modo mais fácil...

```
{"session_key":"5.4Kt_bhcGLE530g.1500797842.40-122201203876562","uid":122201203876562,"secret":"a89s8we0e1f7767c747a0ca69084df","access_token":"**EAAAAAYsX7TsBAsdfosfbsJZBrbPOzrIXkkdoCgqg5oT15RC3ZC4QZCAVg8WLXugwhuYsuUi0E92XBEuTRge0HZC298cwYjNVPbnBZAIpOL9kshfisdisM3MuCg8kALZB0sKjunVWTSMmTYq1dUfK8eQ81i8aNcLmzsfhtdFON6XvmRA5oI8MCVZAOKPD3ROVQbwfwQZA54zGe6zrah6nw5Lz07VrAZD**","machine_id":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T","session_cookies":[{"name":"c_user","value":"122201203876562","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"40:4Kt_bhcGLE530g:2:1500797842:10534:11960","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"8dsdsfsfUvar14Q.AWXQFSahahfsgsk88_-kEag.BWzwiw.0y.Flt.0.0.BZdFuS.AWV8aN6a","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T","expires":"Tue, 23 Jul 2019 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1563869842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true}],"confirmed":true,"identifier":"email_sjn\u0040hotmail.com"}
```

Alguém poderia me informar como posso conseguir isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Deve ter mais de 100 perguntas iguais a essa:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ler+json

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor usar `json_decode`, uma vez que está em formato json.

**Faça assim:**

```
$json_string ='{"session_key":"5.4Kt_bhcGLE530g.1500797842.40-122201203876562","uid":122201203876562,"secret":"a89s8we0e1f7767c747a0ca69084df","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAsdfosfbsJZBrbPOzrIXkkdoCgqg5oT15RC3ZC4QZCAVg8WLXugwhuYsuUi0E92XBEuTRge0HZC298cwYjNVPbnBZAIpOL9kshfisdisM3MuCg8kALZB0sKjunVWTSMmTYq1dUfK8eQ81i8aNcLmzsfhtdFON6XvmRA5oI8MCVZAOKPD3ROVQbwfwQZA54zGe6zrah6nw5Lz07VrAZD","machine_id":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T","session_cookies":[{"name":"c_user","value":"122201203876562","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"40:4Kt_bhcGLE530g:2:1500797842:10534:11960","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"8dsdsfsfUvar14Q.AWXQFSahahfsgsk88_-kEag.BWzwiw.0y.Flt.0.0.BZdFuS.AWV8aN6a","expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1532333842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T","expires":"Tue, 23 Jul 2019 08:17:22 GMT","expires_timestamp":1563869842,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true}],"confirmed":true,"identifier":"email_sjn\u0040hotmail.com"}';

$value = json_decode($json_string);

var_dump($value->access_token);
```

[image: Teste de código]

A variavel `$value` agora contém os valores do json em forma de objeto.

Basta fazer `$value->chave` para obter o valor. No seu caso o valor que deseja é `access_token` portanto substitua `chave` por `acess_token`.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, deu certinho;

Answer (score 0):

@TaissonMartins, olhando nas TAGs de sua pergunta estou imaginando que você também possa usar Javascript, então apesar de você já ter conseguido a resposta que precisava, vai aí mais uma opção. Separei seu JSON apenas para ficar mais fácil de ler...

```
var myObj = {
    "session_key":"5.4Kt_bhcGLE530g.1500797842.40-122201203876562",
    "uid":122201203876562,
    "secret":"a89s8we0e1f7767c747a0ca69084df",
    "access_token":"**EAAAAAYsX7TsBAsdfosfbsJZBrbPOzrIXkkdoCgqg5oT15RC3ZC4QZCAVg8WLXugwhuYsuUi0E92XBEuTRge0HZC298cwYjNVPbnBZAIpOL9kshfisdisM3MuCg8kALZB0sKjunVWTSMmTYq1dUfK8eQ81i8aNcLmzsfhtdFON6XvmRA5oI8MCVZAOKPD3ROVQbwfwQZA54zGe6zrah6nw5Lz07VrAZD**",
    "machine_id":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T",
    "session_cookies":[
                                {
                                    "name":"c_user",
                                    "value":"122201203876562",
                                    "expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT",
                                    "expires_timestamp":1532333842,
                                    "domain":".facebook.com",
                                    "path":"\/",
                                    "secure":true
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"xs",
                                    "value":"40:4Kt_bhcGLE530g:2:1500797842:10534:11960",
                                    "expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT",
                                    "expires_timestamp":1532333842,
                                    "domain":".facebook.com",
                                    "path":"\/",
                                    "secure":true,
                                    "httponly":true
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"fr",
                                    "value":"8dsdsfsfUvar14Q.AWXQFSahahfsgsk88_-kEag.BWzwiw.0y.Flt.0.0.BZdFuS.AWV8aN6a",
                                    "expires":"Mon, 23 Jul 2018 08:17:22 GMT",
                                    "expires_timestamp":1532333842,
                                    "domain":".facebook.com",
                                    "path":"\/",
                                    "secure":true,
                                    "httponly":true
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"datr",
                                    "value":"klt0WVBPc1BWzTSlzlsI0W8T",
                                    "expires":"Tue, 23 Jul 2019 08:17:22 GMT",
                                    "expires_timestamp":1563869842,
                                    "domain":".facebook.com",
                                    "path":"\/",
                                    "secure":true,
                                    "httponly":true
                                }
                            ],
    "confirmed":true,
    "identifier":"email_sjn\u0040hotmail.com"
}

console.log(myObj.access_token);
```

Isso vai imprimir:

```
**EAAAAAYsX7TsBAsdfosfbsJZBrbPOzrIXkkdoCgqg5oT15RC3ZC4QZCAVg8WLXugwhuYsuUi0E92XBEuTRge0HZC298cwYjNVPbnBZAIpOL9kshfisdisM3MuCg8kALZB0sKjunVWTSMmTYq1dUfK8eQ81i8aNcLmzsfhtdFON6XvmRA5oI8MCVZAOKPD3ROVQbwfwQZA54zGe6zrah6nw5Lz07VrAZD**
```

Comment: Obrigado @wBB me esclareceu ainda mais;

Answer (score 0):

Mais gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer isso através do comando explode? Para apenas a parte do token;